# How to fix the width in Horizontal Linear Layout?

Tags: android, layout, alignment

how do I fix the width of each element in the horizontal linear layout. As shown in this picture?

I have updated the question with the code. Help would be appreciated. thank you!

[image]

<

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/l1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="87dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="9dp"
android:paddingLeft="19dp"
android:paddingRight="19dp"
android:paddingTop="9dp"
android:gravity="center"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fbprofile_picture"
    android:layout_width="63dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_new"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fbprofile_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:paddingLeft="17dp"
    android:paddingRight="17dp"
    android:text="Faiza Zainab Ahmad " />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btn_fbfriends_connect"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.31"
    android:background="@color/ThemeLightBlue"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="CONNECT"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

>

Comment: You need to specify gravity for the child elements of the Horizontal layout

Comment: Could you please tell me what would the gravity values be for this problem?

Comment: without your XML all answers are just guesses... show some code

Comment: please paste your xml file here, so it would be easy to solve your problem @FaizaAhmad

Comment: Hi. The code has been pasted @snachmsm

Comment: Hi. The code has been pasted @PratikDasa

Comment: Try the xml in my answer ... it does what you expect, I think

Comment: Have you done for this or not still? @FaizaAhmad

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. It works. :)

Comment: Its okay, looks like you are newbie in android @FaizaAhmad

Comment: True. Thank you.

Comment: Is design completed? @FaizaAhmad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, the ImageView and the Button will keep their size and the TextView will fill the rest of the space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Some text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="The Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does not fix the bug.

Comment: That solution always worked for me, both vertically and horizontal. I just tetsted it and works as expected. Just copy / paste and try.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I must've made some typing error. This works! :)

Answer (score 2):

The better layout implementation would be like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use weights to divide the layout into proportional widths.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your image's width statically. ie: `android:layout_width="96dp"`

And it's best to use **RelativeLayout** rather than **LinearLayout** with **weight**s in this case. ie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The connect TextView's width has already been specified as 100dp.

Comment: 96dp is just an example you can set how much do you want

Comment: Does this mean it is not possible to achieve the same in a linear layout?

Comment: No, you can of course. I just point out the preferred way to do this. This ensures you get the same result from all resolutions.

Comment: This way, the entire text was being displayed but the button's size kept reducing.

Comment: Just give your button a size like 72dp then

Comment: I have. You can check the code I've posted as well, The button size keeps changing according to the text.

Comment: Also, The same bug continues when I fix the button size. The 4th name doesnt get printed

Answer (score 1):

You can add `weightSum` in LinearLayout, and add `layout_weight` to the child of that LinearLayout, for example:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:weightSum="3"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_group_white_24dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: their width should be 0dp in this case

Comment: When I do that, the layout automatically removes the extra ahmad.

Comment: this is not proper answer... with your XML buttons will have 1/6 of width of view/layout/screen - there is no guarantee that this space will be sufficient on every device to show whole button. besides that on large screens, especailly in horizontal, buttons will be very large/wide

Comment: Also, this fixed the problem.  but the view moved out of the screen. How to fix that?

Comment: @santalu this is just for example, you should add the size of the component

Comment: No, in order to use the weights correctly their width should be set 0dp. Otherwise they won't respect the weights you set

Answer (score 0):

To achieve top `LinearLayout` you can use `layout_weight` for `TextView` with value 1 to fit the space between `ImageView` and `Button`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @FaizaAhmad What's the problem?